Was there anything particularly unusual about that quarry near Ytterby?
It's well known that the village of Ytterby in Sweden gave its name to four elements discovered in its quarry: yttrium (Y), erbium (Er), terbium (Tb) and ytterbium (Yb).
Additionally, four other elements not named directly after Ytterby were also first discovered in that very same quarry: scandium (Sc), holmium (Ho), thulium (Tm), and gadolinium (Gd).
Was there anything particularly unusual about the geology of that area that caused all those weird elements to be concentrated in that single quarry?
Or was it just luck? Was it because chemists happened to be working in that area during the golden age of element discovery? Could they have made the same discoveries in other quarries if they had been working elsewhere at the time?

BenM, these types of questions would be more suitable for https://hsm.stackexchange.com (History of Science and Mathematics SE). Thank you for understanding!

But focusing on chemical aspects, it can be said that where is one of those elements, are the other mentioned elements too. Nothing special but being a deposit of rare earth elements, that was the first thoroughly analyzed.  //
It is analogical to a hypothetical case if a deposit of platinum had been discovered and analyzed just in time when distinguishing techniques and chemists were ready to determine/discover all 6 platinum metals, as these are found together,just like rare earth elements/lanthanoids.

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/310/what-are-rare-earths-and-why-do-they-cluster-near-alkaline-magmatism https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/19539/9961

The "rare earths", lanthanides, are fairly widely distributed, though not highly concentrated, and could have been found in China, Brazil or elsewhere.
They were discovered, at that particular time (1787), because advances in chemistry, at that time, made it possible. In fact, though the grouped lanthanides were identified in 1787 as being different in some ways from other known substances, it wasn't until Henry Mosely, in 1914, used X-ray spectroscopy to identify all the components of the lanthanide series.
As for being found together, their chemical properties are so similar that where one of the lanthanides is found, others are located. The actinides also have similar chemistry, so that separating out the europium, neodymium and other elements needed for phosphors, magnets and such leaves mine tailings with large amounts of radioactive thorium and sometimes uranium.
